# math.random in java

Tags: java, random

Hi
consider that I have a `for` loop : `for(int i = 0;i<4;i++)`

in the `for` loop ,I want to print the random of numbers from 0 till 3 and the result include just 3 numbers from this.and each time that for loop execute ,the result of math.random must be different i.e.,
I have 4 numbers : (1,2,3,4)
and I want to have 4 results after for loop executes: [1,2,3] [1,2,4] [2,3,4] [4,1,3]
how can i produce these numbers?
thanks

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear. First you're talking about numbers 0 to 3, then 1 to 4... please clarify, as well as giving examples of what you've tried so far and what it's not doing for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an idea:

1. make a "master" list that will hold all your needed elements, from 0 to 3 (or 1 to 4, whatever you need)
2. [shuffle](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) the list using `Collections.shuffle`
3. turn that list into a stack
4. pop everything from stack
5. repeat 2-4 as needed

Step 4. is the one where you will get all your elements randomly, without duplication.

Note: in step 3., you can also create a new list from the master list instead of a stack if it seems easier, but the basic premise is the same.